# Java replacement for C macros

Tags: java, c, macros, refactoring

Recently I refactored the code of a 3rd party hash function from C++ to C. The process was relatively painless, with only a few changes of note. Now I want to write the same function in Java and I came upon a slight issue.

In the C/C++ code there is a C preprocessor macro that takes a few integer variables names as arguments and performs a bunch of bitwise operations with their contents and a few constants. That macro is used in several different places, therefore its presence avoids a fair bit of code duplication.

In Java, however, there is no equivalent for the C preprocessor. There is also no way to affect any basic type passed as an argument to a method - even autoboxing produces immutable objects. Coupled with the fact that Java methods return a single value, I can't seem to find a simple way to rewrite the macro.

Avenues that I considered:

- **Expand the macro by hand everywhere:** It would work, but the code duplication could make things *interesting* in the long run.
- **Write a method that returns an array:** This would also work, but it would repeatedly result into code like this:

  ```
  long tmp[] = bitops(k, l, m, x, y, z);

  k = tmp[0];
  l = tmp[1];
  m = tmp[2];
  x = tmp[3];
  y = tmp[4];
  z = tmp[5];
  ```
- **Write a method that takes an array as an argument**: This would mean that all variable names would be reduced to array element references - it would be rather hard to keep track of which index corresponds to which variable.
- **Create a separate class e.g. `State` with public fields of the appropriate type and use that as an argument to a method**: This is my current solution. It allows the method to alter the variables, while still keeping their names. It has the disadvantage, however, that the `State` class will get more and more complex, as more macros and variables are added, in order to avoid copying values back and forth among different `State` objects.

How would you rewrite such a C macro in Java? Is there a more appropriate way to deal with this, using the facilities provided by the standard Java 6 Development Kit (i.e. without 3rd party libraries or a separate preprocessor)?

Comment: Use macros, and run the C pre-processor on your code =).

Comment: I would just use the `State` objects as you do.

Comment: "it would be rather hard to keep track of which index corresponds to which variable." - there's always `final int` variables for that kind of thing. So it's probably not that bad, since if you squint a bit `state[k]` looks a lot like `state.k`, but obviously still not preferred.

Comment: I love my Java, but it does have some serious shortcomings :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 3, create you own MutableInteger wrapper class.

```
struct MutableInteger{
  public MutableInteger(int v) { this.value = value;}
  public int value;
}

public void swap3( MutableInteger k, MutableInteger l, MutableInteger m) {
  int t = m.value;
  m.value = l.value
  l.value=k.value;
  k.value=t;
}
```

Comment: +1 Considering that I have already written a whole bunch of Mutable* classes, I don't know why I didn't think about this. I should probably bang (softly) my head on the desk and get either more sleep or more coffee...

Comment: The "sleep" option is highly recommended.

Comment: @Stephen my sleep method throws `CryingBabyInterruptedException` ;-(

Comment: There was a time we used arrays of size 1 for pointer-like uses (such as capturing non-final variables in anonymous inner classes). I don't really do Java any more, I guess now a `Mutable<T>` generic class would be the way to go?

Comment: @Steve Jessop: Generics do not work for primitive types. Using a generic class for such a type would imply using e.g. Integer, with all the performance issues of autoboxing...

Answer (score 1):

> Create a separate class e.g. State
>   with public fields of the appropriate
>   type and use that as an argument to a
>   method

This, but as an intermediate step. Then continue refactoring - ideally class State should have *private* fields. Replace the macros with methods to update this state. Then replace all the rest of your code with methods that update the state, until eventually your program looks like:

```
System.out.println(State(System.in).hexDigest());
```

Finally, rename `State` to `SHA1` or whatever ;-)

Comment: +1 This would definitely work, as long as the `State` class is not static. I guess the context switch from C to Java has left me a little confused, because I was set on the hash methods being all static for no reason whatsoever...

Comment: @thkala: it does depend a bit whether you want the Java code to look like the C code or not. For instance if the author of the C code will make changes in future, and you'll have to update the Java code to match, then you might *not* want to rewrite it in a more OO way, because in that particular case it would actually impede maintenance rather than assisting it. But if this is a one-off rewrite, definitely refactor as far away from the original source as you need.